# Force numeric input in a Gtk::Entry widget

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I'm searching for a possible method to only allow numeric input in a Gtk::Entry widget, without relying on SpinButtons. The matter is, I found a template for this ([link](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtkmm-list/2004-May/msg00169.html)), but it just won't work. I can compile it along my other code, but if I want to declare an instance with

```
NumericEntry<int> int_entry(1,0,10);
```

it tells me

> expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant

The second part is, that I have no clear idea how to pack this entry, because I get a

> can't convert to widget

error when using

```
functionname.pack_start(int_entry())
```

I guess there is a stupid error an my part (bad combination of C++ and Gtkmm newbie), so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Philosophy moment: I'm never a fan of restricting inputs like this.  What if I have the number I want already on the clipboard, with a couple of extra letters, and copy/paste it...then I'll delete the numbers?  Text inputs should be text inputs--check it before you proceed and flag it if it's no good--but don't write brittle hooks that cripple the standard widget behavior.  You cause more problems than you solve.

Comment: Thanks for this idea, I will see what I get implemented first. My reasoning for the numeric input is the context: the user should give kinetic data for an enzyme and that is always purely numeric, so I thought it would be easier to just restrict the input.

Comment: There's a lot more we can do with software when we shift from thinking about how to *restrict* input to thinking about how to *process* input.  For an example: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2898/how-to-create-bands-of-number-ranges-for-a-field/

Comment: ok, I will see that I just check the inputs in the widgets then, thanks for the help and sorry that I didn't reply for a while. Can someone close this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to only allow numbers is to subclass Gtk::Entry and override the on_insert_text() virtual function. In that virtual function, you can validate the text entered and only call the base class's on_insert_text() when the text validates.

```
void NumberEntry::on_insert_text(const Glib::ustring& text, int* position)
{
    // allow only numbers to be entered
    if (contains_only_numbers(text))
        Gtk::Entry::on_insert_text(text, position);
}
```

Comment: In case anyone is struggling with defining a "contains_only_numbers" function...
`bool NumberEntry::contains_only_numbers(const Glib::ustring& text)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        if(Glib::Unicode::isdigit(text[i]) == false)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without subclassing. This is written in Rust but it should work the same in other languages.

```rs
fn is_non_ascii_digit(c: char) -> bool {
    !c.is_ascii_digit()
}
fn entry_disallow(entry: &gtk::Entry, pattern: fn(char) -> bool) {
    entry.connect_insert_text(move |entry, text, position| {
        if text.contains(pattern) {
            glib::signal::signal_stop_emission_by_name(entry, "insert-text");
            entry.insert_text(&text.replace(pattern, ""), position);
        }
    });
}

// To use it
entry_disallow(&entry, is_non_ascii_digit);
```