# is there a way to take numerical inputs in gtk+, pygobject?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I need to implement a input dialog box that takes in numerical values. How is it done in Pygobject?. It is similar to excel taking numerical inputs.

Comment: I was going to suggest to override the do_input_text virtual method and I was writing you a sample, unfortunately I cannot make it work, so I reported a bug. I don't really see another method to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for simple numerical values, you can use [`Gtk.SpinButton`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/SpinButton.html).

The more general way getting input from the user in the UI is [`Gtk.Entry`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Entry.html). That widget does not support built-in validation, but it can be trivially implemented, similarly as shown in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10282948/2921914) (by overriding the `insert_text` method).

If you want to show validation errors to your user, you can use either CSS styling, or for example set the secondary icon (with e.g. the [`secondary_icon_name`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Entry.html#Gtk.Entry.props.secondary_icon_name) property) to a warning sign, with an accompanying label explaining what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from Ricardo Silva Veloso, this is basically the code I was suggesting to write in my first comment (also considering @nielsdg secondary icon suggestion):

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyEntry(Gtk.Entry, Gtk.Editable):
    __gtype_name__ = 'MyEntry'
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyEntry, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def do_insert_text(self, text, length, position):
        if text.isnumeric():
            self.props.secondary_icon_name = None
            self.get_buffer().insert_text(position, text, length)
            return length + position
        else:
            self.props.secondary_icon_name = "dialog-error"
            self.props.secondary_icon_tooltip_text = "Only numbers are allowed"
            return position

win = Gtk.Window()
myentry = MyEntry()

win.add(myentry)

win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```